# Daily Time Series Anomaly Detection - Python

Tags: python, pandas, detection

I have data tracking occupancy over time in a pandas dataframe in the following format:

[image: Data Frame]

The entire data set looks like this:

[image: Chart]

I have data like this for hundreds of properties, and I'd like to set up an algorithm that detects when occupancy gets abnormally low based on historical patterns that include seasonality and randomness. I've scoured through many different ideas online but most seem to deal with real time anomaly detection using sensor data in an IOT environment. Any ideas would be very helpful.

Thanks

Comment: You could assume a distribution on the data, e.g. a normal distribution. For each day, for each property, calculate the z-score of the current occupancy, if it falls below some threshold you define, you can trigger a broader alert.

It may be worth looking at Q/As on https://stats.stackexchange.com/ as this doesn't seem to be a programming problem.

Comment: Oh okay, thank you. I'll try that